# In OpenCV, setting exposure causes my webcam software to not automatically adjust exposure

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam, skype

When I call the method `cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, 2);`, it sets the exposure of the camera as it should. However, when I run my Dell Webcam Central software, or Skype, or anything else that uses my camera, the exposure is stuck at the last exposure that I set it on in the OpenCV program code, and it does not adjust automatically like it had done before.

How can I get my webcam programs (Dell Webcam Central and Skype) to automatically adjust exposure again?

Here's the code:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY ); //CV_CAP_ANY
    if ( !capture )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n" );
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    cvNamedWindow( "mywindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);

    int width = (int)(cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH));
    int height = (int)(cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
    IplImage* image = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

    IplImage* frame;
    char c;
    while ( true )
    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        if ( !frame ) 
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n" );
            getchar();
            break;
        }
        cvShowImage( "mywindow", frame );
        cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, 2);
        c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if( (c & 255) == 27 ) break;
    }
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvDestroyWindow( "mywindow" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could just disconnect and reconnect the camera?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV merely calls `v4l1_ioctl()` passing the argument `V4L2_CID_EXPOSURE`.

You'll have to dig into the [V4L2 docs](http://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/legacy/video4linux/API/V4L2_API/spec-single/v4l2.html) to be able to figure this one out.

By the way, have you tried passing the value `0` for `CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE` after you destroy the window? This might do the trick.

Comment: I am running Windows 7. Are the `v4l1_ioctl()` and `V4L2_CID_EXPOSURE` unique to Linux? What does OpenCV call in Windows?

Comment: I tried the following at the end of the main method:
 `cvDestroyWindow( "mywindow" );
 cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, 0);
 cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
 return 0;`
but it did not "do the trick".